# Entity Framework prevent insert date between two dates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my project user can select 2 dates `startDate` and `endDate`. The selected `startDate` must be greater than the largest `endDate` stored in SQL Server:

[image]

How can I check this using an Entity Framework Linq statement?

```
 _context.tableName.where(p => p.startDate >= ??);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work for you, adapt it to your needs

```
if (startDate > _context.tableName.Max(p => p.endDate))
```